# Why can't I break out of the while loop?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

I've been trying to create a dictionary of countries and their capital based on user input, but I can't seem to break out of the loop even though I made an instance where it should end where the user enters "Q","Q" as a pair

```
capital_dict = {}

country,capital = input("Enter Country, Enter Capital").split(',')

while ('country','capital') != ('Q','Q'):
    capital_dict['country']=capital
    country,capital = input("Enter Country, Enter Capital").split(',')
else:
    print(capital_dict)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Look at this line:

```
while ('country','capital') != ('Q','Q'):
```

That line is never going to be `True` because strings don't change, look at first tuple, it's a tuple of strings, which should be a tuple of variables, so if you replace that line with:

```
while (country,capital) != ('Q','Q'):
```

It will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using strings instead of variable names for your comparison.

Also note you can avoid repeated logic via a `while True` clause:

```
capital_dict = {}

while True:
    country, capital = input("Enter Country, Enter Capital").split(',')
    if (country, capital) == ('Q', 'Q'):
        break
    capital_dict['country'] = capital

print(capital_dict)
```